# Renderscript Error: no memory object set to this allocation

Tags: java, android, android-camera2, renderscript

I am working on a YUV->RGBA converter for android's camera2 that gets its input via GPU texture and returns a `byte[]` (and the image size).

This works fine on all devices that I tested but on Samsung Galaxy S9+ I also get the following error messages on the first run of the script:

```
E/RenderScript(14384): Error: no memory object set to this allocation: 0x72072c2c80
D/RenderScript(14384): [RS-DIAG] A used allocation is not supported on the GPU
D/RenderScript(14384): [RS-DIAG] Launching CPU script : slot(1) 46 0x71cad8a000
```

and then on later runs:

```
D/RenderScript(14384): [RS-DIAG] GPU disabled due to earlier error
D/RenderScript(14384): [RS-DIAG] Launching CPU script : slot(1) 47 0x71cad8a000
```

I could not find anything about the two error messages on top. I noticed that the script still seems to work as expected since the correct output is generated.

I am fine with the script not running on the GPU but the fact that renderscript reports an error and not just a warning throws me off.

I guess my real question is: Is this error safe to ignore or will it fail on other devices/newer versions?

Just for reference, here is my code:

```
import android.graphics.ImageFormat;
import android.renderscript.Allocation;
import android.renderscript.Element;
import android.renderscript.RenderScript;
import android.renderscript.Type;
import android.util.Log;
import android.util.Size;
import android.view.Surface;

public class YUV420Converter implements Allocation.OnBufferAvailableListener {
    private static String TAG = "YUV420Converter";
    private Allocation mYUVInputAllocation;
    private Allocation mOutputAllocation;
    private Allocation mDummyInputAllocation;
    private Size mPreviewSize;
    private ScriptC_yuv2rgb mScriptC;
    private BGRA8888Listener mBGRA8888Listener;

    public interface BGRA8888Listener {
        public void newByteArray(byte[] bytes, Size size);
    }

    YUV420Converter(RenderScript rs, Size dimensions, BGRA8888Listener mBGRA8888Listener) {
        mPreviewSize = dimensions;
        this.mBGRA8888Listener = mBGRA8888Listener;
        createAllocation(rs, dimensions);

        mScriptC = new ScriptC_yuv2rgb(rs);
        mScriptC.set_gCurrentFrame(mYUVInputAllocation);
        mYUVInputAllocation.setOnBufferAvailableListener(this);
    }

    private void createAllocation(RenderScript rs, Size dimensions) {
        Type.Builder yuvTypeBuilder = new Type.Builder(rs, Element.YUV(rs));
        yuvTypeBuilder.setX(dimensions.getWidth());
        yuvTypeBuilder.setY(dimensions.getHeight());
        yuvTypeBuilder.setYuvFormat(ImageFormat.YUV_420_888);
        mYUVInputAllocation = Allocation.createTyped(rs, yuvTypeBuilder.create(),
                Allocation.USAGE_IO_INPUT | Allocation.USAGE_SCRIPT);

        Type.Builder rgbTypeBuilder = new Type.Builder(rs, Element.RGBA_8888(rs));
        rgbTypeBuilder.setX(dimensions.getWidth());
        rgbTypeBuilder.setY(dimensions.getHeight());
        mDummyInputAllocation = Allocation.createTyped(rs, rgbTypeBuilder.create(),
                Allocation.USAGE_SCRIPT);
        mOutputAllocation = Allocation.createTyped(rs, rgbTypeBuilder.create(),
                Allocation.USAGE_SCRIPT);
    }

    public Surface getInputNormalSurface() {
        return mYUVInputAllocation.getSurface();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBufferAvailable(Allocation a) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Beginning conversion");
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        // Get to newest input
        mYUVInputAllocation.ioReceive();

        // Run processing pass
        mScriptC.forEach_yuv2rgb(mDummyInputAllocation, mOutputAllocation);
        
        byte[] b = new byte[mPreviewSize.getWidth() * mPreviewSize.getHeight() * 4];
        mOutputAllocation.copyTo(b);
        Log.d(TAG, "Conversion took " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - start) + " ms");
        mBGRA8888Listener.newByteArray(b, mPreviewSize);
    }
}
```

Which is used like in this pseudocode:

```
renderScript = RenderScript.create(activity);
yuvConverter = new YUV420Converter(renderScript, yuvCaptureSize, bgra8888Listener);

List<Surface> surfaces = new ArrayList<>();
surfaces.add(yuvConverter.getInputNormalSurface());
cameraDevice.createCaptureSession(surfaces, ... );

captureRequestBuilder.addTarget(yuvConverter.getInputNormalSurface());
cameraCaptureSession.capture(captureRequestBuilder.build(), ...);
```

Answer (score 1):

No idea about the actual error, but you could try using the android intrinisc for that (yes, the output is RGBA):
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/renderscript/ScriptIntrinsicYuvToRGB

Comment: Well I'd like my output to be BGRA ordered but that could be worked around. I tried the intrinsic but something did not work. I believe could not figure out how to push the input as SurfaceTexture.

Comment: You use it the exact same way you use your other kernel. Set the input allocation you created, call for_each with the output allocation given

Comment: Thanks for making me try again. I don't know what prevented me the last time but inserting the intrinsic in the current code worked. As I said, I still need to correct the channel order but this is not part of this question. I upvoted but won't accept this answer though, because it did not address the error message.

Comment: No, but each invocation creates a log message about an intrinsic being run.